# Can we make only one of the multiple tbody section scrollable ? Please suggest

Tags: html, css

I have multiple tbody's in single table. Is it possible to make only one among them to be scrollable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Just attach this to `tbody` you want to scroll:

```
.scroll {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    display: block
}
```

Of course `height` you'll ajust to your needs, but it have to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/7/).

Simply define a `height` and set `overflow` to `auto`.

```
tbody.scroll {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

If you want to use multiple columns, make sure to set the display of `thead` and `tbody` to `block`:

```
thead , tbody{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Actually i need only one tbody to be scrollable. Other tbody's, thead should be fixed. Could you please guide me further.Thanks

Comment: I check in IE before.That example worked fine as expected in firefox 8.0.1. But it is not working in IE 8.